# Find proportion of values for two levels that share a common level

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
group <- c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b')
year <- c(1990, 1990, 2000, 2000)
freq <- c(100, 120, 130, 170)
df <- data.frame(group, year, freq)
```

For each distinct year, I'd like to find the freq value for the row with group `a` divided by the freq value for the row with group `b` and add these proportion values to the dataframe. The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
group <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c')
year <- c(1990, 1990, 1990, 2000, 2000, 2000)
freq <- c(100, 120, 100/120, 130, 170, 130/170)
df <- data.frame(group, year, freq)
```

I tried to get this going with the ugliest of loops below but have taken the train off of the rails. If anyone can help show me how to accomplish this elementary task in R, I'd be grateful!

```
for (year in unique(df$year)) {
  a = df[ which(df$group == 'a' & df$year == year), ]
  b = df[ which(df$group == 'b' & df$year == year), ]
  proportion = a$freq / b$freq
  row = c('c', year, proportion)
  rbind(df, row)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` option

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    spread(group, freq) %>%
    mutate(c = a / b) %>%
    gather(group, freq, -year) %>%
    arrange(year, group)
#  year group        freq
#1 1990     a 100.0000000
#2 1990     b 120.0000000
#3 1990     c   0.8333333
#4 2000     a 130.0000000
#5 2000     b 170.0000000
#6 2000     c   0.7647059
```

Explanation: We `spread` data from long to wide, add a column `c = a / b` and `gather` data from wide to long before re-ordering rows to reproduce your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Split original by year with function `split` (result is a list).

```
foo <- split(df, df$year)
```

For each entry in list `foo` bind original entry `x` with new data.frame which has calculated `freq`

```
bar <- lapply(foo, function(x)
              rbind(x, data.frame(group = "c", 
                                  year = x$year[1], 
                                  freq = x$freq[1] / x$freq[2])))

# Bind back final result as it's a list (lapply result)
do.call(rbind, bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'year', concatenate 'group' with 'c' as well as 'freq' with the ratio of 'freq' elements correspondingly

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(group = c(group, 'c'), freq = c(freq, freq[1]/freq[2])), .(year)]
#   year group        freq
#1: 1990     a 100.0000000
#2: 1990     b 120.0000000
#3: 1990     c   0.8333333
#4: 2000     a 130.0000000
#5: 2000     b 170.0000000
#6: 2000     c   0.7647059
```

---

Or  `rbind` the summarised dataset with the original

```
rbind(setDT(df), df[, .(freq = Reduce(`/`, freq), group = 'c'), .(year)])
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_by(year) %>% 
   summarise(group = list(c(group, 'c')), 
            freq = list(c(freq, freq[1]/freq[2]))) %>% 
   unnest
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#   year group    freq
#  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#1  1990 a     100    
#2  1990 b     120    
#3  1990 c       0.833
#4  2000 a     130    
#5  2000 b     170    
#6  2000 c       0.765
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(group = c("a", "b", "a", "b"), year = c(1990, 
1990, 2000, 2000), freq = c(100, 120, 130, 170)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```